# MySQL Workbench 1146 error with table alias

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-workbench, alias

I have this code of MySQL in workbench

```
1. SELECT `ΟΝΟΜΑΣΙΑ_ΠΡΟΪΟΝΤΟΣ`, `ΠΩΛΗΣΗ`
2. FROM(SELECT `ΟΝΟΜΑΣΙΑ_ΠΡΟΪΟΝΤΟΣ`, SUM(`ΠΟΣΟΤΗΤΑ`) AS `ΠΩΛΗΣΕΙΣ`
3. FROM `hospital`.`προιοντα`, `hospital`.`χρεωσεις_περιστατικων`
4. WHERE `hospital`.`προιοντα`.`ΚΩΔΙΚΟΣ_ΠΡΟΪΟΝΤΟΣ` = `hospital`.`χρεωσεις_περιστατικων`.`ΚΩΔΙΚΟΣ_ΠΡΟΪΟΝΤΟΣ` AND YEAR(`ΗΜ_ΝΙΑ_ΧΡΕΩΣΗΣ`) = 2013
5. GROUP BY `ΟΝΟΜΑΣΙΑ_ΠΡΟΪΟΝΤΟΣ`) AS `Π`
6. WHERE `ΠΩΛΗΣΗ` = (SELECT MAX(`ΠΩΛΗΣΕΙΣ`) FROM `Π`.`ΠΩΛΗΣΕΙΣ`);
```

The problem exists in line 6. MySQL Workbench doesn't recognize table alias "Π", so it throws me the error:

> Error Code: 1146. Table 'π.πωλησεισ' doesn't exist.

What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

That's because `Π` is a derived table and not a permanent table and so you can't use it in `WHERE` clause like a normal table. rather include the `MAX()` calculation in outer query.  Change your query like below

```
  SELECT `ΟΝΟΜΑΣΙΑ_ΠΡΟΪΟΝΤΟΣ`, `ΠΩΛΗΣΗ`
   FROM
    (
    SELECT `ΟΝΟΜΑΣΙΑ_ΠΡΟΪΟΝΤΟΣ`, 
    `ΠΩΛΗΣΗ`,
    SUM(`ΠΟΣΟΤΗΤΑ`) AS `ΠΩΛΗΣΕΙΣ`
     FROM `hospital`.`προιοντα`, `hospital`.`χρεωσεις_περιστατικων`
     WHERE `hospital`.`προιοντα`.`ΚΩΔΙΚΟΣ_ΠΡΟΪΟΝΤΟΣ` = 
    `hospital`.`χρεωσεις_περιστατικων`.`ΚΩΔΙΚΟΣ_ΠΡΟΪΟΝΤΟΣ` 
     AND YEAR(`ΗΜ_ΝΙΑ_ΧΡΕΩΣΗΣ`) = 2013
     GROUP BY `ΟΝΟΜΑΣΙΑ_ΠΡΟΪΟΝΤΟΣ`
     HAVING `ΠΩΛΗΣΗ` = MAX(`ΠΩΛΗΣΕΙΣ`)
    ) AS `Π`;
```

PS: BTW, I didn't knew MySQL works in `Alien Language` as well.

Comment: Still, with these adjustments, Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'ΠΩΛΗΣΕΙΣ' in 'field list' as it seems it can't see the SUM(\`ΠΟΣΟΤΗΤΑ\`) AS \`ΠΩΛΗΣΕΙΣ\` column

Comment: Thank you for answering. A new error popped up in this, Error Code: 1111. Invalid use of group function